# Can't Figure Out Correct :child Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the `<a>` tag within the last `<li>`. I am apparently terrible at :child selectors. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="">This Tag</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#nav>li:last-child a
```

The `>` is a child selector that matches only those elements (in this case `li`s) that are immediate descendants of the parent element (in this case `#nav`)

The `:last-child` is a pseudo class that does exactly what it says on the tin; matches the last child (in this case, of type `li`) of an element (or all the last children in a group of nested elements).

And then you just have your standard descendant selector to get to the `a`. Although, as it is an immediate descendent of the `li`, the `>` selector should be used instead for the sake of efficiency.

- [More information on child
  selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)
- [More information on pseudo
  classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)
- [Overview of CSS
  selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: Perfect. No need to explain as I can see how it works now that you have shown me the correct syntax! Very much appreciated. Will mark correct answer when timer allows.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a bit more detail, nonetheless, for the benefit of anyone tripping over this question in the future. If I've answered your question to your satisfaction, can you please accept the answer? :)

Comment: There's a time restriction on accepting an answer. Seems to be 10 minutes after op.